# WordPress responsive menu different when move it to live server

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, plugins

i was working on website and it was work fine when i was work on test server

in responsive view there is menu with + icon that open sub menu see [here](http://websolutions.tedata.net/poultry_exchange/)

when i move it to live server here the website [link](http://www.electronicstockmarketforpoultry.com/)

this + icon disappear and cant open the sub menu also , and the map down not show too

i try to fix it with css adding this code :-

```
.sub-menu li {
    float: none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

#cshero-header-navigation ul#menu-main-menu > li > a:before
{
    content: "+";
    font-size: 28px;
    }
}
```

but its not work

Comment: ,Your theme Amelia??

Comment: Please check in private browser.I can see menu there.

Comment: yes i use Amelia theme , sorry what you mean by private browser?

Comment: I mean to say check in private window.

Answer (score 0):

on your live server following code is not rendered in menu section

```
<span class="cs-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="hidden"></span></span>
```

Comment: Copy your whole menu section from dev server and past this code in client server

Comment: you mean to copy the header.php?

Comment: Yes, You should move header.php for menu section

Comment: i did and nothing change its the same